# how to keep files selected for upload on the input files object when selecting more files?

Tags: javascript, file, upload, multer, preview

I am trying to make an upload page which is able to preview, add and remove files more than once before uploading.
In terms of previewing I made it. But once uploading it uploads only files existing on the files list lastly selected by file input selector from local storage!
for example on a failed attempt! the preview section after manipulating  photos I am left with 10 photos but when I upload them it only uploads 3 images:

[image]

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, length: 3}
    0: File {name: '3-9.jpg.webp', lastModified: 1657529033690, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 11 2022 13:13:53 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 31082, …}
    1: File {name: '10-1-2.jpg.webp', lastModified: 1657529077864, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 11 2022 13:14:37 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 47664, …}
    2: File {name: '11-4.jpg.webp', lastModified: 1657529004794, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 11 2022 13:13:24 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 49742, …}
    length: 3
    [[Prototype]]: FileList
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use more than one file control for this. As you select, hide it and show. On server side, get all files from all input files (named `file0`, `file1`, etc).

```js
var arr_files = [];
var arr_inputs = []
var index = 0;
var file_inputs = document.querySelector(".file_inputs");

function changed(file_input) {
  var files = (file_input.files);
  Object.values(files).forEach(function(file) {
    arr_files.push(file.name);
  })
  // console.log(arr_files);
  var input = document.querySelector("[name='file" + index + "']");
  index++;
  var next = createElementFromHTML(input.outerHTML);
  next.setAttribute('name', 'file' + index);
  file_inputs.appendChild(next);
  input.style.display = 'none';
}


function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();

  // Change this to div.childNodes to support multiple top-level nodes.
  return div.firstChild;
}

function do_submit(form) {
  console.log(arr_files)
  console.log(form.elements)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="do_submit(this); return false">
  <p>
    Choose some files, then choose some more.
  </p>

  <div class="file_inputs">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="file0" multiple onchange="changed(this)">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I used above still not able to edit photos one by one once previewed. however I exploited the a feature called dataTransfer(). and it worked well to pass a new list of files into a new input and replace it with the old one, no matter how many times the old one has been used!